# Python Data Grouping and compare on the basis of date

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science, data-analysis

I  have a set of data where I want to do, If the latest **st_1** or **st_2** are greater than earlier **st_1** or  **st_2** put True or False respectively in another column. How can I do that on the basis of **date** and **id**?

```
id  date                        st_1    st_2
1   2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00   60.0    6.0
2   2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    0.0
2   2021-12-31 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    4.0
3   2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00   60.0    0.0
4   2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00   63.3    2.66
4   2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00   60.0    3.0
4   2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    2.0
5   2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    3.0
4   2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    2.0
5   2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    3.0
5   2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00   80.0    2.0
5   2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    3.5
```

My expected outcome:

```
id  date                        st_1    st_2  outcome
1   2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00   60.0    6.0   false
2   2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    0.0   false
2   2021-12-31 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    4.0   true
3   2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00   60.0    0.0   false
4   2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00   63.3    2.66  false
4   2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00   60.0    3.0   true
4   2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    2.0   true
5   2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    3.0   false 
5   2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00   80.0    2.0   true
5   2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00   70.0    3.5   true
```

Comment: Kindly add your expected output dataframe

Comment: @sammywemmy I have added my expected outcome

Comment: Is the expected output supposed to have the same number of rows as the original df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update #2: I fixed the sorting to sort first by id and then by date and added column lag_id which is now used to ensure that comparisons are made only within the same id

Update: I just noticed the the spec is "If the latest st_1 or st_2 are greater than earlier st_1 or st_2" which means that the correct answer is to use "|" instead of the original answer's "&". Corrected.

Code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
string = """id  date st_1 st_2
1  "2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00"  60.0    6.0
2  "2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00"  70.0    0.0
2  "2021-12-31 00:00:00+00:00"  70.0    4.0
3  "2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00"  60.0    0.0
4  "2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00"  63.3    2.66
4  "2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00"  60.0    3.0
4  "2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00"  70.0    2.0
5  "2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00"  70.0    3.0
4  "2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00"  70.0    2.0
5  "2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00"  70.0    3.0
5  "2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00"  80.0    2.0
5  "2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00"  70.0    3.5
"""
data = io.StringIO(string)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+")  # Load df0 from the data string
df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], inplace=True)  # Sort according to the spec
print(df)

df['lag_id'] = df['id'].shift(1) # Lag the id column

df['lag_st_1'] = df['st_1'].shift(1)  # Create column lag_st_1 with the st_1 data lagged by 1 row
df['lag_st_2'] = df['st_2'].shift(1)  # Ditto for st_2
print(df)

# Create result column with True values where the right conditions are met
df.loc[(df['id'] == df['lag_id'])
        & (
              (df['st_1'] > df['lag_st_1'])
            | (df['st_2'] > df['lag_st_2'])
          ), 'result'] = True

# The previous operation fills the rest of the rows with NAs.
# Here we change the NAs to "False"
df['result'] = df['result'].fillna(False)
print(df)
```

Updated output:

```
    id                       date  st_1  st_2
0    1  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  60.0  6.00
1    2  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  0.00
2    2  2021-12-31 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  4.00
3    3  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  60.0  0.00
4    4  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00  63.3  2.66
5    4  2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00  60.0  3.00
6    4  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  2.00
8    4  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  2.00
7    5  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  3.00
9    5  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  3.00
10   5  2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00  80.0  2.00
11   5  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  3.50
    id                       date  st_1  st_2  lag_id  lag_st_1  lag_st_2
0    1  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  60.0  6.00     NaN       NaN       NaN
1    2  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  0.00     1.0      60.0      6.00
2    2  2021-12-31 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  4.00     2.0      70.0      0.00
3    3  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  60.0  0.00     2.0      70.0      4.00
4    4  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00  63.3  2.66     3.0      60.0      0.00
5    4  2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00  60.0  3.00     4.0      63.3      2.66
6    4  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  2.00     4.0      60.0      3.00
8    4  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  2.00     4.0      70.0      2.00
7    5  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  3.00     4.0      70.0      2.00
9    5  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  3.00     5.0      70.0      3.00
10   5  2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00  80.0  2.00     5.0      70.0      3.00
11   5  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  3.50     5.0      80.0      2.00
    id                       date  st_1  st_2  lag_id  lag_st_1  lag_st_2  result
0    1  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  60.0  6.00     NaN       NaN       NaN   False
1    2  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  0.00     1.0      60.0      6.00   False
2    2  2021-12-31 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  4.00     2.0      70.0      0.00    True
3    3  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  60.0  0.00     2.0      70.0      4.00   False
4    4  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00  63.3  2.66     3.0      60.0      0.00   False
5    4  2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00  60.0  3.00     4.0      63.3      2.66    True
6    4  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  2.00     4.0      60.0      3.00    True
8    4  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  2.00     4.0      70.0      2.00   False
7    5  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  3.00     4.0      70.0      2.00   False
9    5  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  3.00     5.0      70.0      3.00   False
10   5  2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00  80.0  2.00     5.0      70.0      3.00    True
11   5  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  70.0  3.50     5.0      80.0      2.00    True
```

Comment: The values of st_1 & st_2 should be compared with the same id. here I can see you compare the values of id 5 with id 4 rows also.

Comment: I used `df['end_date'] = df.groupby('id')['SOFAS'].shift()` to compared the datw with same id's.

Comment: @Irbaz - Does the "result" column meet your requirements in my latest update #2?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to check the conditions with the dates, but not have one date tested against a previous date. The logic in C Pappy's answer is better than this but this does the checks only within the date group, therefore it results in fewer 'True'. Please let us know which is correct.

```
df.sort_values(['date', 'id'], inplace=True)
df['st_1_check'] = False
df['st_2_check'] = False

def test_conditions(x):
    if x.shape[0] > 1:
        x.loc[:, 'st_1_check'] = x['st_1'] - x['st_1'].shift(1)
        x.loc[:, 'st_2_check'] = x['st_2'] - x['st_2'].shift(1)
    return x

dfnew = df.groupby(['date']).apply(test_conditions)
dfnew.fillna(False, inplace=True)
dfnew['st_1_check'] = np.where(dfnew['st_1_check'] > 0, True, dfnew['st_1_check'])
dfnew['st_2_check'] = np.where(dfnew['st_2_check'] > 0, True, dfnew['st_2_check'])

dfnew['st_1_check'] = np.where(dfnew['st_1_check'] <= 0, False, dfnew['st_1_check'])
dfnew['st_2_check'] = np.where(dfnew['st_2_check'] <= 0, False, dfnew['st_2_check'])
dfnew

    id                       date     st_1    st_2 st_1_check st_2_check
4    4  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00 63.30000 2.66000      False      False
7    5  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00 70.00000 3.00000       True       True
9    5  2021-06-30 00:00:00+00:00 70.00000 3.00000      False      False
5    4  2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00 60.00000 3.00000      False      False
10   5  2021-08-31 00:00:00+00:00 80.00000 2.00000       True      False
1    2  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00 70.00000 0.00000      False      False
3    3  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00 60.00000 0.00000      False      False
11   5  2021-10-31 00:00:00+00:00 70.00000 3.50000       True       True
2    2  2021-12-31 00:00:00+00:00 70.00000 4.00000      False      False
0    1  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00 60.00000 6.00000      False      False
6    4  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00 70.00000 2.00000       True      False
8    4  2022-02-28 00:00:00+00:00 70.00000 2.00000      False      False
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def func_date(x):
  if x==0:
    return 0
  elif df.at[x-1,'st_1']>df.at[x,'st_1']:
    return 'higher'
  elif df.at[x-1,'st_1']==df.at[x,'st_1']:
    return '='
  else:
    return 'less'

df['result']=df.index.map(func_date)
print(df)
```

Comment: The values of st_1 & st_2 should be compared with the same id. we can't use x-1 because we don't know that on the x-1 position the id is the same or different.